# What is causing my light level to drop?

Tags: destiny-2

While playing Destiny 2 last night, my light level was roughly 1218 with my currently equipped gear. When I logged on this morning, my light level drastically reduced to 1067.

This doesn’t seem to be just a display thing. I was doing activities in Europa, and enemies who were once easy became too difficult. What may have caused this reduction of my light level? My other two guardians appear to be unaffected and their light was the same.

I have attached a screenshot as reference for my gear and their respective light.

[image: light level too low]

Comment: This happens whenever they disable something that you currently have equipped. Happened to me when they disabled witherwhore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [Hotfix 3.0.1.3](https://www.bungie.net/en/Explore/Detail/Update/49994) , the Vesper of Radius is no longer disabled and can equipped

> Fixed an issue where Warlocks could emit a damage impulse using Vesper of Radius without using their Rift charge.
>
> - With this resolved, Vesper of Radius may once again be equipped.

---

After additional investigation, I discovered the culprit was the exotic chest plate [Vespur of Radius][1].

I went through and unequipped my gear with different ones. When I came to the chest plate, I was unable to re-equip Vesper of Radius. Supposedly overnight, [Bungie had disabled](https://twitter.com/BungieHelp/status/1335058145966604288) this exotic armor piece due to newly discovered bugs.

Since the chest plate was effectively disabled, the light calculation was considering the power level as 0. Thus skewing my overall light level that's taken from the average of all equipped gear